# how to create windows service using crud operations in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, insert, windows-services, crud

I want to create windows service which perform CRUD operations using any database such as MS-Sql/MySQL Server for run that service in the background to execute some tasks like Insert, Update and Delete operation on database. I have already created simple Windows Service for Send Mail on particular time interval but right now want to perform CRUD operations using Windows Service and I create one  windows service which runs fine i.e. Service Start Succesfully after installing it but CRUD operations not performing through this service.

code written is -

```
public void InsertData()
{
     string name = "Vijay Patil";
     string Address = "Kolhapur";
     string Emailid = "Test@gmail.com";
     string mbno = "9012345678";

     string insert = "USP_UserInfo_Insert";
     objconn.cn.Open();
     objconn.cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, objconn.cn);
     objconn.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     objconn.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
     objconn.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address_user", Address);
     objconn.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailID", Emailid);
     objconn.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobilenumber", mbno);
     int a = objconn.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     if (a > 0)
     {
       Library.WriteErrorLog("Saved Rec...");
      }
}  


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  InsertData();
  Library.WriteErrorLog("Data Saved successfully");
}
```

Can any one tell me is it right way to perform CRUD operations using Windows Service ?

Please help me.

Comment: What' stopping you? What problem/errors do you have/facing?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to create a webservice. 
Maybe you should check thoses topics first :

- aspnet core : to create a web service using C# with the lastest Microsoft framework
- RESTful web services : to perform CRUD operations directly in the url you'll call
- Entity framework : to connect your webservice with your sql database

You can start with:
https://dzone.com/articles/step-by-step-aspnet-core-restful-web-service-devel

Comment: Thanks @Ted0s for reply. But i need to perform these CRUD operationd using windows services only.

Comment: Hum, ok sorry for the misunderstanding. 
Do you have specific errors/problems in your code ?